HMAC-SHA256 encryption in WSO2 E.I
I want to HMAC-SHA256 encryption in WSO2 EI but I cant able to find the way.
I have tried with below JS snippet but it gives library CryptoJS not found error
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret");
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

What could be the solution to perform hmac encryption in wso2?

You can use a java class mediator[1] to achieve your requirement.
[1] https://mcvidanagama.medium.com/hash-strings-in-wso2esb-wso2ei-1b8f4a8f5ae3

java class implementations resolved my problem. Thanks
